# Дигитализация или диджитализация?

Tags: лексика, заимствования

Какой из вариантов этого слова (дигитализация или диджитализация) более **частотный** и какой в большей степени **подходит** для лексики русского языка.

Какие у этого слова есть русские **синонимы**, нужно ли оно вообще?

Comment: Академос фиксирует "дигитализацию". // Возможные русскоязычные варианты: цифровизация (но, к сожалению, этот термин трудами конспирологов стал приобретать негативный окрас); оцифровка, оцифровывание.

Comment: Вы не могли бы дать ответ, хотя бы короткий. Почему у слова появился негативный окрас и как этому способствовали конспирологи?   Оцифровка, цифровизация – достаточно ли нам этих слов (у последнего, кстати, неудобная фонетика)? Кажется, диджитализация применяется чаще, чем дигитализация. А здесь какая фонетика лучше? Эти слова имеют стилевую пометку?

Comment: Ответ требуется слишком объёмный, а потом ещё и защищать его, аргументировать... Не, моя слишком глуп, тем более в вопросах лексики (хотя тут, скорее, морфемика: какой там суффикс более русский, какой более по смыслу подходит и т. п.).

Comment: Понятно, но причина скорее другая. А вот некоторые (не будем говорить конкретно) работают на форуме аки пчелы... Ну хотя бы про конспирологов скажите пару слов.

Comment: Определённые круги православных и околоправославных видят в цифровизации различные опасности, от вполне реалистичных (тотальный контроль перемещения и покупок-продаж, утечки личных данных) до вполне мистичных (информация собирается для тайного мирового правительства жидов-рептилоидов; кто-то в своё время видел в штрих-кодах печати антихриста, упомянутые в Апокалипсисе, сейчас различные опасения также присутствуют, в частности касающиеся биометрии). Так что на цифровизации конспирология цветёт буйным цветом. Несмотря на маргинальность таких взглядов, мрачная аура вокруг термина имеется.

Comment: Рептилоиды. Жители планеты Нибиру, настоящей Звезды Зла... Но это же фантастика.

Comment: Это образно-ироническое наименование. Но не удивлюсь, если кто-то всерьёз в это верит.